# Hibernate RevEng Entity: org.hibernate.type.StringType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.VersionType

Tags: java, hibernate

I've used Hibernate's eclipse's tool to reverse engineer an existing database containing about 400+ tables; It generated all the models nicely, but I can't do anything with the models, persist for example throws the exception in the title.

I had to move around the files a bit to make it work under Maven, these are the main files concerned:

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">...</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://dev.mycee.co.za:3306/mycee</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">...</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">mycee</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
        ...
        <mapping resource="za/co/mycee/database/model/Products.hbm.xml" />
        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Products.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jun 6, 2013 1:35:02 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="za.co.mycee.database.model.Products" table="PRODUCTS" catalog="mycee">
        <meta attribute="class-description" inherit="false">Hibernate Entity for table PRODUCTS @author JanM</meta>
        <meta attribute="extends" inherit="false">za.co.mycee.database.methods.Methods</meta>
        <id name="productId" type="int">
            <column name="PRODUCT_ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>

    ...

        <property name="active" type="int">
            <column name="ACTIVE" not-null="true" />
        </property>

        ...

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Products.java:

```
package za.co.mycee.database.model;

// Generated Jun 6, 2013 1:35:01 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.0.0

/**
 * Hibernate Entity for table PRODUCTS
 * @author JanM
 */
public class Products extends za.co.mycee.database.methods.Methods implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int productId;
    ...
    private int active;
    ...
    public Products() {
    }

    public Products(int productId, ..., int active, ...) {
        this.productId = productId;
        ...
        this.active = active;
            ...     
    }

    public int getProductId() {
        return this.productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    ...

    public int getActive() {
        return this.active;
    }

    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    ...

}
```

Methods.java

```
package za.co.mycee.database.methods;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Methods {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Methods.class);
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            log.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex, ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public void persist() {
        log.debug("persisting " + this.getClass() + " instance");
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(this);
            log.debug("persist successful");
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("persist failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR: za.co.mycee.database.methods.Methods - Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate persister org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:174)
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:385)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1760)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1798)
        at za.co.mycee.database.methods.Methods.<clinit>(Methods.java:16)
        at za.co.mycee.payhost.endpoint.SinglePaymentEndpoint.doPayment(SinglePaymentEndpoint.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint.invoke(MethodEndpoint.java:134)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:240)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:233)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:239)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.StringType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.VersionType
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildVersionProperty(PropertyFactory.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:507)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor27.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
        ... 35 more
Jun 06, 2013 4:11:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet spring-ws threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.StringType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.VersionType
        at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildVersionProperty(PropertyFactory.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:507)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor27.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
        at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:385)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1760)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1798)
        at za.co.mycee.database.methods.Methods.<clinit>(Methods.java:16)
        at za.co.mycee.payhost.endpoint.SinglePaymentEndpoint.doPayment(SinglePaymentEndpoint.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.MethodEndpoint.invoke(MethodEndpoint.java:134)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.invokeInternal(DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.java:240)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.invoke(AbstractMethodEndpointAdapter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:233)
        at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
        at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:239)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

If there's a better way to reverse engineer a database using hibernate and maven, please advise (I used the eclipse tool and moved the files to where they should be) or if the exception can be sorted out, that would be super.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring-Roo's Database Reverse Engineering tool works without problems, instead of using the Hibernate RevEng tool, I've successfully reverse engineered a db using Spring Roo:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html